# What is this Macro/Pointer declaration doing?

Tags: c, pointers

anyone familiar with this macro definition:

```
#define CrashData                     (*((CRASH_DATA *)CRASHDATA_ADDRESS))
```

where

```
CRASH_DATA  is a typedef struct
CRASHDATA_ADDRESS is 0xF3F80UL
```

I suspect that we are creating a struct variable called CrashData that is placed from the addrees and forward right?

Thank you for your help, Pointer declaration is kind of confusing.

Comment: It casts the address to a pointer to a struct, and then dereferences the pointer to access that struct. A rather terrible macro, in my opinion.

Comment: It's letting you use `CrashData` as an _lvalue_ so you can access its members as `CrashData.whatever`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suspect that we are creating a struct variable called CrashData that is placed from the addrees and forward right?

No, not exactly.

In the first place, there is no variable anywhere in sight.  You spoke correctly when you called the code a macro definition; therefore the code defines a *macro* named `CrashData`, which is not at all the same thing as a variable.

So let's look at the macro's replacement text:

```
(*((CRASH_DATA *)CRASHDATA_ADDRESS))
```

- Starting from the inside, you claimed that `CRASHDATA_ADDRESS` *is* `0xF3F80UL`, which I interpret to mean that it is actually a macro, with that `unsigned long` constant as its replacement text.
- `(CRASH_DATA *)` can only be a cast operator, so it is unsurprising to hear that `CRASH_DATA` is a `typedef`ed type alias, or perhaps a macro expanding to such.  The result of the cast is a pointer to `CRASH_DATA`.  It *might* in particular point to a block of memory at the address specified by `CRASHDATA_ADDRESS`, but the standard only says

> the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned,
>   might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a
>   trap representation.

- the result of the cast is enclosed in parentheses and the dereferencing operator (unary `*`) is applied to it.  The result of dereferencing a pointer is an lvalue designating the object to which the pointer points.
- the dereferenced result is enclosed in parentheses, which serve their ordinary grouping role.  This is useful so that operator precedence does not cause surprising effects where the macro is used.

Overall, then, the intent of the macro seems to be to represent *an expression* that presents a block of memory starting at `CRASHDATA_ADDRESS` as if it were an object of type `CRASH_DATA`.  Since `CRASH_DATA` is a structure type, you would access its members via the `.` operator:

```
if (CrashData.member1 == y) {
    CrashData.member2 = x;
}
```

Although you might write similar code if `CrashData` were a variable, it is *not* a variable, and there are ways in which it would behave differently than a variable.

Answer (score 0):

First, `((CRASH_DATA *)(CRASHDATA_ADDRESS))` is a typecast, telling the compiler to treat the address defined in `CRASHDATA_ADDRESS` as if it were a pointer to an item of type `CRASH_DATA`.

Next the star (*) operator is dereferencing the pointer. Since it is a pointer to a struct, once referenced you can access any of the struct's members via the dot (.) operator.

You should be able to access the data like this:

```
CrashData.some_struct_member
```

Anyways, what is important is to understand you are not 'creating' a new struct variable, you are only telling the compiler to treat the data stored at memory address 0xF3F80UL as a variable of type `CRASH_DATA`.